# Error handling for applications: how to return a public message error instead of all the chain of errors and tracing it at the same time?

Tags: rust, error-handling, thiserror, anyhow

#### PROLOGUE

I'm using [async-graphql](https://github.com/async-graphql/async-graphql) and I have hundreds of resolvers and for each resolver I would like to trace all the possible errors.

In each method of my app I'm using `anyhow::{Error}`.

Right now I have code similar to this for each resolver:

```rust
#[Object]
impl MutationRoot {
    async fn player_create(&self, ctx: &Context<'_>, input: PlayerInput) -> Result<Player> {
        let services = ctx.data_unchecked::<Services>();

        let player = services
            .player_create(input)
            .await?;

        Ok(player)
    }
}
```

So I thought about using the below code (*note the added line with `.map_err()`*):

```rust
#[Object]
impl MutationRoot {
    async fn player_create(&self, ctx: &Context<'_>, input: PlayerInput) -> Result<Player> {
        let services = ctx.data_unchecked::<Services>();

        let player = services
            .player_create(input)
            .await
            .map_err(errorify)?;

        Ok(player)
    }
}

fn errorify(err: anyhow::Error) -> async_graphql::Error {
    tracing::error!("{:?}", err);

    err.into()
}
```

Now the error is traced along with all the error chain:

```
ERROR example::main:10: I'm the error number 4

Caused by:
    0: I'm the error number 3
    1: I'm the error number 2
    2: I'm the error number 1
    in example::async_graphql
```

#### QUESTION 1

Is there a way to avoid the `.map_err()` on each resolver?

I would like to use the `?` alone.

Should I use a custom error?

Can we have a global "hook"/callback/fn to call on each error?

#### QUESTION 2

As you can see above the chain of the error is the inverse.

In my graphql response I'm getting as `message` the "I'm the error number 4" but I need to get the "I'm the error number 2" instead.

The error chain is created using `anyhow` like this:

- main.rs: returns error with `.with_context(|| "I'm the error number 4")?`
- - call `fn player_create()` in `graphql.rs`: returns with `.with_context(|| "I'm the error number 3")?`
- - - call `fn new_player()` in `domain.rs`: returns with `.with_context(|| "I'm the error number 2")?`
- - - - call `fn save_player()` in `database.rs`: returns with `.with_context(|| "I'm the error number 1")?`

**How can I accomplish this?**

I'm really new to Rust. I come from Golang where I was using a struct like:

```golang
type Error struct {
    error          error
    public_message string
}
```

chaining it easily with:

```golang
return fmt.Errorf("this function is called but the error was: %w", previousError)
```

**How to do it in Rust?**

Do I necessarily have to use `anyhow`?

Can you point me to a good handling error tutorial/book for applications?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you define your own error for your library and handle them properly by using `thiserror` crate.

It's like Go defining `var ErrNotFound = errors.New(...)` and use `fmt.Errorf(..., err)` to add context.

With the powerful tool `enum` in Rust, so you can handle every error properly by `match` arms. It also provides really convenient derive macro like `#[from]` or `#[error(transparent)]` to make error conversion/forwarding easy.

Edit 1:
If you want to separate public message and tracing log, you may consider defining you custom error struct like this:

```rs
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
pub struct MyError {
    msg: String,
    #[source]  // optional if field name is `source`
    source: anyhow::Error,
}
```

and implement `Display` trait for formatting its inner `msg` field.

Finally, you could use macro in `tracing-attributes` crate:

```rs
#[instrument(err(Debug))]
fn my_function(arg: usize) -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: I do not need a custom error enum. I only need to return a public message for consumers and to trace the entire error chain.

Comment: @FredHors Take a look at `#[source]` example in `thiserror` crate and `#[instrument(err(Debug))]` in `tracing-attributes` crate. You may consider define you own error struct and use `Display` trait for public message and `Debug` trait for tracing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to avoid the .map_err() on each resolver?

Yes, you should be able to remove it unless you really need to convert to `async_graphql::Error`.

> Do I necessarily have to use anyhow?

No, but it makes this easier when using `?` on different error types.

> I'm really new to Rust. I come from Golang where I was using a struct like:

Take a look at `thiserror` which lets you build you own `enum` of error variants.

Comment: I do not need a custom error enum. I only need to return a public message for consumers and to trace the entire error chain.